# Reestablishing branch relationships in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I came back to work after a year at college to find out that my project which was originally hosted on a local TFS installation was moved to Visual Studio online. What remained was a flat folder structure with no branches. I converted all the former branches back to branches, but how can I reestablish the relationships between them so that I don't have to do painstaking baseless merges on a year's worth of updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **reparent** the branch. You can do this under the "Branching and Merging" menu on the context-sensitive menu when you right click on a folder in the Source Control Explorer.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what i need. I'll test it out at work tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the reparent dialog is empty, and doesn't allow me to select a branch until I've already done a baseless merge into that branch. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: No -- you're going to have to do a baseless merge first. No matter how you slice it, you're in for a potentially painful merge if the code between the two branches has diverged significantly. That would be the case if the branch had just been left untouched for a year, as well. Here's the million dollar question thought: Is there anything worth saving in the branch? If the codebase has changed enough that a merge is painful, it's unlikely that anything you have in that branch is even going to be relevant anymore.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now that I think about it. Bring on the pain.